# Can I restrict any session from altering or dropping tables

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-queries, sql-sessions

I have a stored procedure which picks data from a particular column from a table and execute that data, which means the data will itself be a query, most probably some update or delete or insert statements.
Now the problem is, there is a high risk of the tables getting altered or dropped because this data can be any statements which the user inserts(of course there are approval scenarios and status checks and all ,but still..) .
And there is a restriction of using the user login(which have ddl permission) for the web app, so I cannot restrict based on login.
Is there any way so that this particular session which executes the statement can be restricted from any ddl permissions?

Comment: `EXECUTE AS` maybe? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql

Comment: On the other hand if there is a known list of operations, why they are stored as queries? Maybe that is the problem you want to solve first.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if security wasn't weakened to begin with. Executing raw SQL, having a single stored procedure do it all instead of having multiple sprocs that could have their own security, giving end users DDL permissions

Comment: Instead of strings in a table the queries could be standalone stored procedures with their own permissions. Instead of giving end users DDL permissions you could create stored procedures that can make modifications and give EXECUTE permissions to specific low-access accounts. You could use `EXECUTE AS` inside each stored procedure to make it run as a different account or with different privileges